# Cannot change swiper next/prev button styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

Here I try to change `swiper-button-next` color to `#444444`, however you can see that my styles are ignored:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    slidesPerGroup: 1,
    loop: true,
    loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
});
```

```css
.swiper-button-next, .swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%…2L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23444444'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E) !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.6/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.6/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide col-md-4">
                    <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x200">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide col-md-4">
                    <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x200">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide col-md-4">
                    <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x200">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide col-md-4">
                    <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x200">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Nope actually it's svg, the color code is within the data url.

Comment: You must be replacing the wrong part of the URL or have a closing `'` somewhere wrong? I'm only guessing as changing the SVG Fill color seems to work in general: `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'><path%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%234444'%2F><%2Fsvg>`

Comment: I just replaced `007aff` with `444444` as it was recommended in [here](https://muut.com/swiper#!/swiper/general:how-to-change-the-color-of).

Comment: @NarūnasK Your URL specified in your CSS seems incomplete/partial. `www.w3.org%…2L2` that `...` seems odd. I was able to get it working by using the original applied URL and simply changing the fill color as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience in SVG but inspecting the URL from your CSS it seems incomplete. Possibly a copy-paste error?

```
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%…2L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23444444'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E) !important;
```

Note `www.w3.org%…` the `...` doesn't look right.

Running your code and copying the current applied URL using inspect in the console and changing the fill color from `007aff` to `444444` works fine.

In addition each of the URLs applied contain the shape of the arrow too so you can create a separate CSS entry for `next` and `prev`.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  slidesPerGroup: 1,
  loop: true,
  loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});
```

```css
.swiper-button-prev {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'><path%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23444444'%2F><%2Fsvg>") !important;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23444444'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E") !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.6/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.6/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x200">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x200">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x200">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x200">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it was a `copy-paste` error, as I've copied this *url* from the browser `developer tools` *styles* section.